# SearchKick search_data vs searchable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

For the sake of this question, let's say I have two models:

- `Book`, which has a `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, and an associated `Author` model.
- `Author`, which has a `name` and `birthdate`.

For the purposes of searching, I want to two distinct searches:

- Search `Book`s by their `name` or `author.name`
- Search `Author`s by their `name`

---

1. Is `search_data` necessary if I only have direct mappings of model fields to ElasticSearch fields? For example, is it sufficient on my `Author` model to **only** have `searchkick searchable %i[name]`, or do I also need:

```ruby
def search_data
  {
    name: name
  }
end
```

2. How do you define nested data in Searchkick to search the `Book`'s `Author.name`? Currently, I would do something like this, however, it seems from the [Nested Data](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#nested-data) section of the README that there might be another way to accomplish the same thing.

```ruby
def search_data
  {
    name: name,
    author_name: author.name
  }
end
```

3. What if a `Book` had *many* `Author`s? What is the suggested way to search a book by any of its author's names? Something like this is the best I could come up with so far:

```ruby
def search_data
  {
    name: name,
    author_names: author.pluck(:name)
  }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you only need model fields, you don't need to define `search_data`. Searchkick does this automatically. You can check this with `Author.first.search_data`.
2. Searchkick has limited support for nested data. The example you gave looks good.
3. That's exactly what's suggested for multiple authors.